# SQL Server - Loop through self-join multiple times

Tags: sql-server, loops, t-sql, self-join

I have a sequel table i.e as follows. It is a list of products and child products. Each product can have multiple children, and each child can have further children. I want to extract each level of this tree of all the products. Below is an example of input and output. Thanks

```
+------+---------+------+
| Prod | Child P | Qty  |
+------+---------+------+
|    A |       B | 1    |
|    A |       C | 2    |
|    A |       D | 1    |
|    B |       E | 2    |
|    C |       F | 2    |
|    F |       J | 4    |
+------+---------+------+
```

I am want to write the T-SQL Code to fetch the entire tree of products. I am expecting output to be as below:

```
+------+---------+------+---------+
| Prod | Child P | Qty  | Level   |
+------+---------+------+---------+
|    A |       B | 1    |    1    |
|    A |       C | 2    |    1    |
|    A |       D | 1    |    1    |
|    A |       E | 2    |    2    |
|    A |       F | 2    |    2    |
|    A |       J | 4    |    3    |
|    B |       E | 2    |    1    |
|    C |       F | 2    |    1    |
|    C |       J | 4    |    2    |
|    F |       J | 4    |    1    |
+------+---------+------+---------+
```

Is there a way to do this in a T-SQL query instead of a stored proc?

Comment: Have you searched for `parent child cte`?

Answer (score 1):

This will do it for you.

```
DECLARE @Product TABLE
(
    Prod VARCHAR(10)
  , ChildProd VARCHAR(10)
  , Qty INT
);

INSERT INTO @Product (Prod, ChildProd, Qty)
VALUES
('A', 'B', 1),
('A', 'C', 2),
('A', 'D', 1),
('B', 'E', 2),
('C', 'F', 2),
('F', 'J', 4)

;WITH cteProduct AS
(
    SELECT Prod
         , ChildProd
         , Qty
         , 1 AS Level 
    FROM @Product
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
               cte.Prod
             , p.ChildProd
             , p.Qty
             , cte.Level + 1
    FROM       @Product   p
    INNER JOIN cteProduct cte ON p.Prod = cte.ChildProd
)
SELECT
         cteProduct.Prod
       , cteProduct.ChildProd
       , cteProduct.Qty
       , cteProduct.Level
FROM     cteProduct
ORDER BY cteProduct.Prod
       , cteProduct.ChildProd;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2db6c6b45c078bc70c4c9f4475bd0346).